# How to identify all MVC controllers using a specific view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm still a bit of a noob when it comes to working with MVC projects in visual studio but I often find it necessary to navigate from a specific view into the details for the business logic used by that view, usually one or more controllers. So far I have only found these approaches.

1. Search for a controller using the "controller" naming convention. If I'm looking at a view called "UserOrder" it is likely that the controller will be named "UserOrderController".
2. Search for the name of the model class in the hope that it was instantiated in the controller class.

My question is whether there is a better way to identify which controller is using a particular view?

Comment: Right click in the view and click _Go To Controller_

Comment: Brilliant, I never noticed the option. Unfortunately when I try it out VS displays an error message saying it was unable to find a matching controller

Comment: Are they partial views?

Comment: Yes the one with the link to "Go To Controller" is a partial view. If I check a regular view I don't have the option to navigate to the controller

Comment: It works fine for a normal view. Are you following convention and naming the view the same as the action method? (the statement in your 1st point suggests your not)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but the code was actually build by another developer so I don't know for sure if they followed any recommendations. If you can provide me with a link to the naming convention I'd be happy to verify it